# how to add timer to the changenotifier class

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

I am using flutter provider package to get data.

I have 2 problems.

1. In the DataProvider class I did initialize & it run 3 times to
   get data,
2. I needs to update the data evey 5 minute(i am updating
   the data via calling the api) how can i excute that, i think needs
   to add Timer fuction.where can i add those.

`

```
class DataProvider with ChangeNotifier {

      DataProvider() {
        getData();
 /*this will call 3 times when i call changenotifier provider in the ui*/
      }
    
      List<Data> _vData = [];
    //<Data> is my mode
      List<Data> get vData => _vData ;
    
       getData() async {
        try {
          _vData = await instatntApi().Services();
    // got the data from service
          notifyListeners();
          return _vData ;
        } catch (e) {
          print("error provider $e");
        }
      }
    }
```

`

here is my ui call

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: ChangeNotifierProvider<DataProvider>(
            create:
                (context) => DataProvider(),
            child:  Builder(
              builder: (
                context,
              ) {
                final model = Provider.of<DataProvider>(context);

                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: model.vData.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      
                      return Center(
                        child: Text(
                          model.vData[index].text.toString(),
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I need you to post the UI that's calling your `Provider`, because that's probably the cause of the triple-call. Are you using a `FutureBuilder` and initializing the `future` directly in it?

Comment: @venir No,I am using changeNotifierProvider in my ui

Comment: @venir Now i updated the ui part in the question

Comment: Could you post the full implementation of your Provider? We need to dig deeper into that `.HomePageList` and `.data` properties I don't see in your implementation

Comment: @venir HomePageList == vData   array in the provider.
now I updated the ui in to it.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not answering with a direct solution, but I'd suggest to use the [Consumer](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Consumer-class.html) class for your purpose. I usually get the data / provider with `var data = Provider.of<DataProvider>(context, listen: ...).myData` and then implement the `builder` method within the `Consumer` class. Try it out, if you haven't found a solution. One more thing: you're performing an asynchronous operation in there, you might want to add a `FutureBuilder`, somewhere...

Comment: sorry,
I forgot to appreciate your work,Thank you bro....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `Timer.periodic`

```
class DataProvider with ChangeNotifier {
   bool _call = false;
      DataProvider() {
        if(!_call){
           getData();
           _call = true;
        }
      }
    
      List<Data> _vData = [];
    
      List<Data> get vData => _vData ;
    
       getData() async {
        await processData();
         Timer.periodic(Duration(minute: 5), (t){
           processData();
         });
      }

      processData() async{
       try {
          _vData = await instatntApi().Services();
    // got the data from service
          notifyListeners();
        } catch (e) {
          print("error provider $e");
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: can I know why that's happens, expect technical answer, bro, did you know any,  anyway thank you for your reply

Comment: still it calls 3 - 4 times when call the initial call & the timer run